# Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Tags: tomcat, ssl, keystore, keychain, keytool

`keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file secure.mysite.com.crt`

> **keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match**

I had followed the instructions in this Apple Technical Note exactly.
**https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2326/_index.html**

This has allowed me to create my own CA identity, and then use that CA to issue an SSL certificate for my internal server (all done through Apple's Keychain). On the server (Tomcat 6), I've used `keytool` to import `.p12` (exported from Apple's keychain) and merge it into a new `.jks` keystore that is later configured in Tomcat. That all worked fine.

However all guides and documentation I come across, [**even the one from Tomcat itself**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html), say to generate a **CSR** from the `keytool` and then import the CA's response cert back into `.jks`. I want to do this through **Certificate Signing Request** method for a number of reason, but I've been struggling to get this to work for couple of days now.

My steps are:

- Create own CA on Apple's Keychain as described in the first link.
- Export own CA as `myCA.cer` as described in the first link.
- From Tomcat's server machine:
  `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks`
  **password:** keystorepass
  **renter pass:** keystorepass
  **first and last name:** secure.mysite.com
  **other info:** stuff
  **Enter key password for `<tomcat>`:** keystorepass
- `keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -keyalg -RSA -keystore keystore.jks -file secure.mysite.com.csr`
- Next I open Apple `Keychain Access` > `Certificate Assistant` > `Create a Certificate For Someone Else as a Certificate Authority...`
- I drag the `secure.mysite.com.csr` to the required area
- Select my own CA, select validity time, provide certificate information
  **Common Name:** `secure.mysite.com`
  and other information
- Make sure that **SSL Server Authentication** is enabled under Extended Key Usage Extension
- Make sure that **dNSName** is `secure.mysite.com` under Subject Alternative Name Extension
- And now I have `secure.mysite.com` (**certificate and private key**) in my Keychain.
- I export `secure.mysite.com` as `.p12` (as in the linked documentation)
- I then extract the cert and key:
  `openssl pkcs12 -in secure.mysite.com.p12 -nokeys -out secure.mysite.com.crt`
  `openssl pkcs12 -in secure.mysite.com.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out secure.mysite.com.key`
- Finally, I am trying to import the certs back to keystore
  `keytool -import -alias root -keystore keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file myCA.cer`
  **Do you want to trust:** yes
  All good.
- `keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file secure.mysite.com.crt`

### **keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match**

I have tried with and without importing the `myCA.cert`.
I have tried exporting `secure.mysite.com` from Keychain directly in `.cer` format.
Started the process from scratch multiple times.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the certificates in order of root first, then the intermediate certificates and finally your own personal server key.
you can check the order of a chain by viewing a the certificates that you were issued and viewing the info.

Answer (score 0):

As per your performed steps, you created a keystore first (a private key got generated in it) and then you tried to import the certificate in keystore. But in the command you didnt use the private key which you converted using `openssl`; you used the private key which freshly got generated when you generated the keystore.

As you have the pfx with you, yo can straight away convert it using the below keytool command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore domain.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore name_of_the_keystore_file.jks -deststoretype jks
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) for issuing of certificates. It has predefined templates for CA, HTTPS server end HTTPS client so it is pretty easy to do what you want.

As for keystore I would suggest to use [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/). Again, nice GUI and pretty easy to use. Export certificate from XCA database and import them using portecle. Then save as jks.

Comment: While I appreciate the alternatives, and will research the suggested application, I do still need to get it working properly through the command line

Comment: It does not matter to me what tool I use if it gets me closer to the objective (task) I am working on. But I will always use one that is easier to use :)

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the last command should be "keytool -importcert" instead of your "keytool -import".

Quoting from documentation for Java 8 (as you do not mention your version of Java) [1]

> You import a certificate for two reasons: To add it to the list of trusted certificates, and to import a certificate reply received from a certificate authority (CA) as the result of submitting a Certificate Signing Request to that CA

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html#keytool_option_importcert

**Update:**

My bad - the command name should not matter. It is later said in the same document that '-import' and '-importcert' are synonyms.

> This command was named -import in earlier releases. This old name is still supported in this release. The new name, -importcert, is preferred going forward.

**Question:**

Does the file `secure.mysite.com.crt` contain a single certificate or a chain of certificates?

According to [1], when it is a chain, the chain shall be ordered with the user (your) certificate first followed by zero or more CA certificates.

I think you can export the public key from your keystore and manually compare it with the one that you are trying to import. OpenSSL has commands to list contents of a certificate.

Comment: Java 7 reference for keytool: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html

Answer (score -1):

Issue :keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks -file secure.mysite.com.crt
**keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match**

Please change the alias from tomcat to any other as you are using the same alias for Keystore -genkey